# Running java code gives Java Hotspot Server VM warning

Tags: 16.04, java

I'm running a Ubuntu 16.04 system. I installed IntelliJ IDEA IDE to program Java but I can't seem to **Run** the program as I get the following error: `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=250m; support was removed in 8.0`.

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by removing the following line `-XX:MaxPermSize=512m`.

It is found in files :

`PATH_TO_INTELLIJ\bin\idea.vmoptions
PATH_TO_INTELLIJ\bin\idea64.vmoptions`

Found the answer in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24706544/how-do-i-make-the-java-hot-spot-maxpermsize-warning-go-away-when-using-intelli).